# \ch03\AddSub.asm(45): fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : IsPrime

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC
.REPEAT
mov edx, OFFSET fPrompt ;display a prompt
call WriteString
call ReadInt ;recordes users number
mov var1, eax           ;gives var1 the users number
.IF var1 == -1       ;jumps to L3 if the user want's to quit
jmp L3
.ENDIF
call IsPrime       ;calls the IsPrime procedure
L3:
.UNTIL var1 == -1       ;jumps up to repeat if var1 != -1
ret
main ENDP
mov ebx, 2   ; sets minimum divisor
mov eax, var1 ; set dividend
cdq ; converts to 64-bit edx:eax
mov ecx, ebx ; stores divisor in ecx
div ecx ; Proformes division
mov b, eax   ; Gets remainder, b is half var2
.WHILE ebx != b   ;loops until ebx has reached var1/2
mov eax, var1 ; set dividend
cdq ; converts to 64-bit edx:eax
mov ecx, ebx ; stores divisor in ecx
div ecx ; Proformes division
mov a, edx   ; Gets remainder
.IF a == 0 ;if there was no remainder, then var1 is not prime
jmp L1       ;jumps out of the loop if above is correct
.ENDIF
inc ebx       ;increments until ebx reaches b
.ENDW
mov edx, OFFSET pPrompt   ;tells the user their number was prime
call WriteString
jmp L2
L1:
mov edx, OFFSET cPrompt ;tells the user their number was not prime
call WriteString
L2: ret
IsPrime ENDP
END main
```

Can anyone help with the error msg im getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `IsPrime ENDP` line but no corresponding `IsPrime PROC`.

That's why it's complaining about the nesting.

You need to work out where the `PROC` line should go (*probably* immediately before `mov ebx, 2 ; sets minimum divisor`) and, ... well, put it there :-)

Comment: Thank you! wow how couldnt I see that! Now that thats fixed its just giving me an undefined symbol error for fPrompt, var1, b, a, pPrompt, and cPrompt. Would that be because I didnt define it under the .code segment?

Comment: I'd probably be more inclined to have it under a data segment somewhere since code tends to be read-only (though it's been a while since I did x86 asm). But yes, they should be defined *somewhere!* If you do that and still have trouble, you'd be better off asking a *new* question since you'll get more exposure than just me.

Comment: Oki Doki!! But you did really help me! Thanks!