# (94): fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : main

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
org 100h ; set location counter to 100h
.code
main PROC
jmp CodeStart

DataStart:
max dw " "
space db " ", 0

CodeStart:
mov bx, 1

call IsPrime

cmp dx, 0


LoopStart:

; must be a prime
mov ax, bx
call print_num

; print a space
mov si, offset space
call print_string

add bx, 1
cmp bx, max

jle LoopStart

ret


IsPrime PROC
; uses a loop to determine if number in bx is prime
; upon return if bx not prime dx will be 0, otherwise dx > 0

; we only have to test divisors from 2 to bx/2

; prepare to divide dx:ax / 2
mov ax, bx
mov dx, 0
mov cx, 2
div cx

; move result into si for loop
mov si, ax

; assume the value is prime
mov dx, 1

; start loop at 2
mov cx, 2

PrimeLoop:

; compare loop count(in cx) and max loop value (in si)
cmp cx, si

; jump out of loop if count(cx) > si
ja StopLabel

; divide test value (in bx) by loop count (in cx)
mov ax, bx
mov dx, 0
div cx

; check remainder (in dx), if zero then we found a divisor
; and the number cannot be prime
cmp dx, 0

; if dx = 0 then we found a divisor and can stop looking
je StopLabel

; increment count
add cx, 1

jmp PrimeLoop

StopLabel:

ret
IsPrime ENDP

END IsPrime
```

Im having trouble with this error says its on my last line? Can anyone shed light as to what could be the problem?

Comment: This is your second question,very similar to your [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561264/ch03-addsub-asm45-fatal-error-a1010-unmatched-block-nesting-isprime). While we are glad to help, I think you seriously need to start developing some problem solving skills. When you came across an error you cannot fix, start by removing functional blocks until it goes away. Then put them back one by one. Once you know the faulting block, write a new minimal source that reproduce the error. This is the [mcve] and it is very good to isolate errors.

Comment: Start by removing `IsPrime` and see if you can spot any asymmetry. Also please take some time to get confident with [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you think you'll need to ask more questions.

Comment: Why is there data placed in the code section, rather than in the data section where it belongs? Why is `org 100h` used in this program?

Answer (score 1):

The [`END`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxy1fb5k.aspx) directive should not have anything following it. This directive indicates the end of the entire file, not a specific scope, so you don't need to name the scope.
<sub>(Although you *can* optionally follow `END` with the name of the entry point procedure, which in your case would be `main`, this is not necessary and infrequently done in my experience.)</sub>

Note that this is in contrast to [`ENDP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/566af882.aspx) (end procedure), which is prefixed with the name of the procedure that is coming to an end (the one started with the [`PROC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01d2az3t.aspx) directive).

The last three lines should look like this:

```asm
IsPrime ENDP   ; end the IsPrime procedure

END            ; end of the entire file
```

Your code would be *significantly* easier to read if you indented the lines according to each's scope. Moreover, I suspect that would then allow you to find your own "unmatched block nesting" errors.

For example, you would also notice that there is no `ENDP` directive for the `main` procedure!

---

A corrected (and nicely formatted!) version:

```asm
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data
org 100h ; set location counter to 100h


.code

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Main
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

main PROC
    jmp CodeStart

  DataStart:
    max dw " "
    space db " ", 0

  CodeStart:
    mov bx, 1
    call IsPrime
    cmp dx, 0

  LoopStart:
    ; must be a prime
    mov ax, bx
    call print_num

    ; print a space
    mov si, offset space
    call print_string

    add bx, 1
    cmp bx, max

    jle LoopStart

    ret
main ENDP

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; IsPrime
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

IsPrime PROC
    ; uses a loop to determine if number in bx is prime
    ; upon return if bx not prime dx will be 0, otherwise dx > 0

    ; we only have to test divisors from 2 to bx/2

    ; prepare to divide dx:ax / 2
    mov ax, bx
    mov dx, 0
    mov cx, 2
    div cx

    ; move result into si for loop
    mov si, ax

    ; assume the value is prime
    mov dx, 1

    ; start loop at 2
    mov cx, 2

  PrimeLoop:

    ; compare loop count(in cx) and max loop value (in si)
    cmp cx, si

    ; jump out of loop if count(cx) > si
    ja StopLabel

    ; divide test value (in bx) by loop count (in cx)
    mov ax, bx
    mov dx, 0
    div cx

    ; check remainder (in dx), if zero then we found a divisor
    ; and the number cannot be prime
    cmp dx, 0

    ; if dx = 0 then we found a divisor and can stop looking
    je StopLabel

    ; increment count
    add cx, 1

    jmp PrimeLoop

  StopLabel:
    ret
IsPrime ENDP


END
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxy1fb5k.aspx), `END` is allowed to have an operand, which is the entry point address. That probably should be `main` not `IsPrime` though.